# How do you map numbers (salaries) to a range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have salary data and I am trying to map them back to a range in another table.

For example, the `salary` table:

```
| id | amount | currency | 
|----+--------+----------|
|  A |  11111 |      USD |
|  B |   5000 |      EUR | 
|  C |  45000 |      RMB |
|  D | 100000 |      USD |
|  E | 110000 |      EUR |
|  F |  67000 |      RMB |
```

I have another table, `bands_pay` with a `label` that denotes the salary band. For example:

```
| label |       range     | currency | 
|-------+-----------------+----------|
|    1A |   10000 - 15000 |      USD |
|    2C | 100000 - 149999 |      EUR | 
|    3P |   25000 - 49999 |      RMB |
|    4F |   35000 - 49999 |      EUR |
|    5B |     5000 - 9999 |      EUR |
|    6Q | 100000 - 124999 |      USD |
|    7F |   50000 - 74999 |      RMB |
```

How can I join these tables to return all the contents of the `salary` table and with the correct `label`?

```
| id | amount | currency | label |
|----+--------+----------+-------|
|  A |  11111 |      USD |    1A |
|  B |   5000 |      EUR |    5B |
|  C |  45000 |      RMB |    3P |
|  D | 100000 |      USD |    6Q |
|  E | 110000 |      EUR |    2C |
|  F |  67000 |      RMB |    7F |
```

Comment: Could your store `range` for two columns?

Comment: Fix your data model to store the range as two integer columns rather than as a string.  Don't store information using the wrong data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should split range column to 2 column:

-label   -start range  -end range  -currency

and then :

```
select salary.id,salary.amount,salary.currency,bands_pay.range
from salary,bands_pay
where
bands_pay.start_range<=salary.amount and salary.amount<bands_pay.end_range
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `numrange` for that purpose. Description [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html).

For example:

```
With SalaryRanges(SalaryRange) AS (
VALUES(NumRange(0,5000)), (Numrange(5000,10000)), (NumRange(10000,15000)), (NumRange(15000,25000)), (NumRange(25000,50000)), (NumRange(50000,100000)), (NumRange(100000,150000))
),
Salary(id, amount, currency, label) as (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A','B','C','D','E','F']),
    UNNEST(ARRAY[11111,5000,45000,100000,110000,670000]::numeric[]),
    UNNEST(ARRAY['USD','EUR', 'RMB', 'USD','EUR', 'RMB']),
    UNNEST(ARRAY['1A','5B','3P','6Q','2C','7F'])
)
SELECT *
FROM Salary S
JOIN SalaryRanges SR on SalaryRange @> Amount
```

If you decide to store the ranges into a table, you'll probably want to create an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION).
Otherwise you'll need to decide what to do with overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Since your range values are not in separated columns (it would be better if they were), you need to first split the `range` column using `regexp_split_to_array` then join the two tables and check which range fits the amount of each salary:

```
select s.id, s.amount, s.currency, bp.label from salary s join (
select a[1] as from, a[2] as to
from (
    select regexp_split_to_array(range, '-')
    from bands_pay
     ) as dt(a)) bp
on s.id >= bp.from and s.id <= bp.to
```